# Could we have a distinct style for answer links?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Could we get a unique styling for answer hyperlinks? Currently, question and answer links look exactly the same — the color, anyway.

This is more a functional request than an aesthetic one, because it would enable you to quickly tell answer from question at a glance (in the rep history, flag history, moderator tools, etc.). Sometimes there are additional text hints (for example "asked" vs. "answered" in the flag queue), but that's not really at a glance because you have to read a word and that's *hard work*.

I guess I should just show you what I mean. I changed the answer link color to the color [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) uses with a user style.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://gaming.stackexchange.com/)
{
    .answer-hyperlink {
        color: #555555 !important;
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

- [rep history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mETB.png)
- [moderator tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8PhZ.png)
- [moderator tools #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrdH0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented in the new site's design - question links are blue, answer links are green.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite non intuitive. It rather looks like visited/non-visited links. I think that if you want to make questions and answers visually distinct, you should do so textually.

Comment: Well, I admit I don't actually know what a visited link looks like here, I have that option turned off. But that's only an example, of course, it doesn't have to be gray(ish). I still think it could work. Other sites already do this. All of the trilogy sites, for example.